# Pump control with a Raspberry Pi

Tags: power-supply, transistors, raspberry-pi, grounding, output

Pump control Raspberry Pi

[image]

I am planning to control a small water pump with my Raspberry Pi. The 24V pump  needs quite a bit of current (~1A) so thats why I got a transistor output card with an I2C bus. I've got everything programmed and set up except the pump. I will connect the pump to output 1 (A1) and the ground on my 24V power supply. +24V will be connected to +Vs.

Where do I need to connect the GND (green arrow?) Do I need to connect it to the GND of my Raspberry Pi or to the GND of my 24V power supply? I only got this one output card and I want to make sure before I burn anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should connect that Ground terminal to the negative side of the 24 V power supply.  The opto-couplers isolate the 24 V part of your circuit from the Raspberry Pi circuit.